# Issues with "Read More" feature of my website

Tags: php

I need your help with doing a Read More feature for my website. Contents that the Read More feature will be applied on are generated dynamically. When I implement it, and I click the Read More...i'm taken to the same page and the full article dosent show.

Please how can I fix this.

Thank you.

```
<?php

$row['article_content'];

if (strlen($row['article_content']) > 500) {
  $shortText = substr($row['article_content'], 0, 100);
    $shortText .= '... <a href="site/article.php?id=' . $id . '">Read More</a>
 echo $shortText;
```

}
     ?>

Comment: What is the page that has this code?

Comment: Where do you define $id?   Perhaps $row['id']?

Comment: What is the value of your $id?

Comment: Then offcourse it will execute the same page will display same thing.  You can show shorter versions on another page. and then for read more you can show it on article.php. If you just want keep them on same page and want to expand it when read more is clicked, Use javascript.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. `'">Read More<` < You open a double and single quote here, but you don't close any of them. Is this your real code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['readmore']))
echo $row['article_content'];
else
echo get_short_text($row['article_content']); 


function get_short_text($article)
 {
   $shortText="";
   if (strlen($article) > 500) {
       $shortText = substr($article, 0, 100);
       $shortText .= '... <a href="site/article.php?id=' . $id . '&readmore=1'>Read More</a>
   }
   else { $shortText = $article; }

   return $shortText;
 }
```